# Прошу пояснить, зачем мастер использовал lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Здравствуйте.

В книге Марка Лутца, в главе, посвящённой lambda-функциям есть один не ясный мне пример. Пожалуйста, поясните, зачем там вообще лямбда и почему нельзя просто поместить в command sys.stdout.write

```
import sys
from tkinter import Button, mainloop

x = Button(
    text = 'Press me',
    command=(lambda:sys.stdout.write('Spam\n')))
x.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: А _как ещё_ её туда поместить? Как вы предлагаете записать это?

Comment: command=(sys.stdout.write('Spam\n'))

Comment: Ну, и что произойдёт? Код `sys.stdout.write('Spam\n')` будет выполнен _немедленно_, и возвращённое значение будет записано в `command`. А что реально нужно?

Comment: Почему немедленно? Немедленно по нажатию кнопки ведь?

Comment: Ну, нет, вы передаёте в качестве параметра не выражение (я думаю, так в Питоне вовсе нельзя), а _значение_ выражения. Так что выражение будет сначала вычислено, а уж его результат попадёт в command. Ну вы сами попробуйте же.

Comment: VladD но ведь command это параметр Button. Он не вызывается до клика по кнопке. Вычисление происходит при нажатии, когда нужно обработать command, а не при создании кнопки. Разве это не так ?

Comment: Ну, вот когда вы функции передаёте аргументы, они вычисляются же не внутри функции, а до вызова?

Comment: @VladD да, но ведь button имеет конструктор, который обращается к command только когда происходит событие press, также как вычисление после def начинается после ВЫЗОВА функции, а не при создании. Но, кажется, я начинаю понимать, что в питоне всё не так и лямбда нужна в качестве ингибитора выполнения, так как на неё ставится точка остановки вычисления, ибо питон не умеет работать с атрибутами так, как мне это было знакомо в других языках. Понял, спасибо вам.

Comment: Ну, вопрос-то не в том, когда происходит доступ к command, а **что** в этот самый command записывается.

Comment: В данном случае в  command передается функция (вернее вообще callable) которая будет вызвана по клику (калбэк), а ламда - возможность не создавать отдельную именованную функцию для этого. В питоне типично, как и в других языках. Никакого "ингибиторства" тут нет.

Answer (score 3):

Параметр `command` принимает функцию, которая будет вызвана по нажатию на кнопку. `lambda` создаёт функцию (такой же объект, который создаётся `def` конструкцией, но состоящий  только из одного выражения). Если убрать `lambda:`, то `command` будет присвоен результат вызова метода `.write()` (вероятно кол-во записанных символов, что не является функцией).

Запись `f()` в Питоне означает: вызвать функцию, на которую имя `f` ссылается. Если записать `f(arg=g(1))` в Питоне, то `g(1)` вызывается **до** вызова `f` функции, то есть это равнозначно:

```
tmp = g(1)
f(arg=tmp)
```

где `tmp` это результат (возвращаемое значение из `g` функции). К примеру:

```
def g(x):
    return x + 1
```

тогда `tmp == 2` и поэтому `f(arg=g(1))` равнозначно `f(arg=2)`. В вашем примере, если убрать `lambda:`, то `.write()` метод вызываетcя и Button видит `command=5` (возвращаемое значение из `sys.stdout.write("Spam\n")`). `5` не является функцией, поэтому это неверно.

В Питоне функции являются обычными объектами: вы можете их передавать в другие функции, возвращать из функций, помещать в списки, словари, итд.

`lambda` позволяет создать анонимные функции прямо по месту. То есть вместо:

```
def write_spam():
    return sys.stdout.write("Spam\n")

Button(..., command=write_spam)
```

можно записать просто:

```
Button(..., command=lambda: sys.stdout.write("Spam\n"))
```

- [Зачем нужны Lambda-функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534344/23044)
- [Как работают lambda-функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612763/23044)