# Python threading vs processing

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Здравствуйте!

Есть два скрипта:

**1) Threads.py**

```
import threading
import os
from time import sleep

class A:
    def __call__(self, count=6, sleep_time=0.5):
        for i in range(count):
            # print('Working class A, i=%s' % i)
            # sleep(sleep_time)
            x = 10
            for j in range(50000):
                x *= 10 ** 9  # какая-то долгая операция
            print('Working class A, i=%s' % i)


class B:
    def __call__(self, count=6, sleep_time=0.5):
        for i in range(count):
            x = 10
            for j in range(50000):
                x *= 10 ** 9        # какая-то долгая операция
            print('Working class B, i=%s' % i)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=a, kwargs={'sleep_time': 0.7})
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=b, args=(12,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

**2) processes.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
from time import sleep

class A:
    def __call__(self, count=6, sleep_time=0.5):
        for i in range(count):
            # print('Working class A, i=%s' % i)
            # sleep(sleep_time)
            x = 10
            for j in range(50000):
                x *= 10 ** 9  # какая-то долгая операция
            print('Working class A, i=%s' % i)


class B:
    def __call__(self, count=6, sleep_time=0.5):
        for i in range(count):
            x = 10
            for j in range(50000):
                x *= 10 ** 9        # какая-то долгая операция
            print('Working class B, i=%s' % i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()

    p1 = Process(target=a, kwargs={'sleep_time': 0.7})
    p2 = Process(target=b, args=(6,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

**Оба выдают следующий результат:**
1)

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test1/Threads.py
Working class A, i=0
Working class B, i=0
Working class A, i=1
Working class B, i=1
Working class A, i=2
Working class B, i=2
Working class A, i=3
Working class B, i=3
Working class A, i=4
Working class B, i=4
Working class A, i=5
Working class B, i=5
Working class B, i=6
Working class B, i=7
Working class B, i=8
Working class B, i=9
Working class B, i=10
Working class B, i=11
```

2)

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test1/Processes.py
Working class B, i=0
Working class A, i=0
Working class B, i=1
Working class A, i=1
Working class B, i=2
Working class A, i=2
Working class B, i=3
Working class A, i=3
Working class B, i=4
Working class A, i=4
Working class B, i=5
Working class A, i=5
```

**Вопрос!**
Из прочитанных описаний данных функций, я понял так, что потоки подвержены одному GIL, а процессы имеют свой GIL каждый.
Соответственно, как я понимаю, в примере №1 с потоками результат должен был бы быть: сначала все выводы class A, затем class B (примерно).
На деле же получается, что и потоки и процессы выполняются полностью параллельно.
Запускал на Python 3.6.1

Кто-нибудь может объяснить, почему потоки исполнялись параллельно?
Это какое-то изменение в Python, котрое оптимизировало работу потоков?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Изначально, оригиналы скриптов и разъяснение нашел тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452762/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85

Comment: объяснение было неверно. Я добавил [свой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/654031/23044)

Comment: в сторону: зачем вы используете `class B: def __call__(self):...` вместо `def b(): ...`?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Что касается использования Классов - просто скопировал пример, чтобы проверить.

Comment: Из того, что я понял - GIL не держит поток до его конца, а переключается через каждые n инструкций или по другому алго (зависит от версии питона). То есть ведет себя примерно так же, как планировщик потоков на однопроцессорном комьютере - каждому потоку отдается квант времени и потоки постоянно (по возможности) переключаются. Но GIL мешает использовать истинную параллельность на нескольких процессорах.